# How to convert structured references in Excel to table references?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to have more "meaningful" formulas in my Excel columns. Tables provide a nice way to do that and I'd like to convert my existing sheets to use tables and automatically turn the formulas that use A1 notation into equivalent formulas with table references, such as:

Before:

| Foo | Bar | Baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | = A2+B2 |

After:

| Foo | Bar | Baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | = [@Foo] + [@Bar] |

Alternatively, how could I use column aliases? I've been able to set the column aliases, but when I use "apply names", the formulas become broken (`#spill`)

Comment: You're probably going to need VBA to convert regular references to table references. You should also be aware that formulas that spill cannot be used in tables. Usually though they can be rewritten into a formula that does not spill.

Comment: Structured references are intended to work with tables (insert - table), not with simple named ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you Define Name in Excel and you want to use the Name in formula?
Try this Define Name first and select the name from the list in formula:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here. The first is easy. A little work, not much, but easy. The second is a bit more subtle and so might be trickier to solve.

When you convert a range to a Table, immediately (not precisely critical nothing else be done first, but the sooner, the better) convert the formulas.

How? Well, when you created the Table out of the range, Excel linked the formulas in each column. So if column B had `=D1+G1`, it still does. So do the rows beneath it. Press `F2` to enter the editing mode and in the formula bar, slowly (or quickly if there are only a couple references) work your way through the "A1-style" references like so:

1. Use the mouse to highlight an entire reference (`D1` as an example).
2. Note that Excel highlights where it refers to.
3. Click that cell or range with the mouse.
4. Note how the formula's reference changes from `D1` to `[@Foo]`.

Continue on. I think I would do the more complicated references, ones that have ranges, first since once you obscure everything with all those "easy to read" structured references, small spots like `D1` will be hard to see amongst all the verbiage cluttering up the somehow "clearer and cleaner formula."

As a practical matter, since ranges that store things begging to be a Table would be expected to refer mostly to single cells in the same row the formula you are editing is in, it should likely be pretty easy.

Once you've changed the references to all structured references, press `ENTER` to save the result. Actually, if there are lots of references to change, DO save after every few you do so you don't get vexed by things going wrong.

Now that you have a changed formula, notice if all the formulas in the column changed, or did not. You'd probably see them change, like the column was a barber pole that moved in chunks, not continuously... so like it rolled around from left to right. But be sure to look in the next cell to make sure.

They will have all changed IFF they all had the related formula. If they had, Excel linked them when making the Table. This is what lets Excel copy formulas into new rows when you start the next one up.

Important:  make sure this happened. If it did not, it means that the column had AT LEAST one cell with a non-matching formula. You may have Excel's error indicating turned on for unmatched formulas, in which case it should be fairly easy to locate the offending formulas. Check each and make sure there is no reason they cannot be fixed to the standard version. For instance, some dummy using the spreadsheet might've wanted a value to be six more than it was and just added a `+6` to your formula. Fix each situation, as desired, but if you fix them all, you can just copy the formula you produced at the top of the column down the whole thing. Each would require its own fix, the example given for instance might be fixable by removing the addition altogether, or perhaps by deciding what column's value can be adjusted to get the same effect out of the standard formula. Each thing will be different, but the goal is to fix them all so you can copy the formula down.

That way you get one of the nicer effects of a Table, the automatic populating of cells that need formulas in new rows you make.

So, quickly and easily, likely, and it's all done. Next column. But even if not quickly, it's still "monkey work" and just needs trudged through.

Second question, not asked, but clearly of interest. You mentioned applying the Named Ranges to the formulas on a sheet, presumably essentially in the Table, and having results disappear, showing the `#SPILL!` error instead.

This is assuredly due to any such replacement Named Range containing a `dynamic reference`. So, Named Range `Horse` might have `=C2#` as its `Refers to` value. Or uses one in a formula. The Named Range need not literally contain the actual letters and numbers of such, but rather could refer to something on the sheet or in another Named Range which is, or contains, a `dynamic reference`.

Why does this matter? Because Tables ABSOLUTELY will not work with `dynamic references`. Period. Not in any way will they do so. If you convert a range reference, say, in a Table's formula to a Named Range that somehow contains or references a `dynamic reference`, the formula will immediately give the `#SPILL!` error.

In fact, in a new fact to me, experimentation shows that even a normal range in the formula will trigger errors. Partly, the errors occur since the formula fills down the column and they interfere with each other like a dynamic range needing more cells than are available. Part is just stupid, but a fact. Table formulas seem to fail with any range, be it vertical, horizontal, or 2-D. Not even dynamic ranges, just normal ranges like `I1:I29`. Related, clearly, to what it is that dynamic ranges themselves do that causes failure in Tables.

Not much else will, and nothing else will in the circumstances described. It's hard to see how your description of the problem could be mistaken given how simple and straightforward what you say about it is. So...

Lots of possibilities to maybe have to trace. But in any particular spreadsheet, the offending reference will probably be pretty easy to spot, once you know it needs spotting. Harder if you a hundred columns, 73 formulas, 28 Named Ranges, and 7 of them have one or more ranges. Even harder if those ranges are critical to your work.

But most usages for such ranges in such work would be a desire to do relative referencing. So in row 6, one wants the value from row 6 of the range. Since Excel fills the formulas down, you can achieve that by just referencing the single value appropriate to the row you are in as a single cell. So if in row 6 of the Table, needing the row 6 value from a reference like `W1:W2098`, you'd do that just by referencing `W6` in your row's formula. When it populates the column, it will adjust for each row and draw the correct value from the `W1:W2098` range. It just requires a different look at things, an easy to understand one once you learn of it.